# Dictionary gives "TypeError: string indices must be integers" when i pass it as an argument to a function

Tags: python, json

I manage to send this json to my server:

```
data  =  {'transformations': '{"translate":{"z":-1.2,"y":-3,"x":-2},"scale":{"y":2,"z":2,"x":2},"rotate":{"x":90,"z":20,"y":80}}', 'part_id': 'cube10mm', 'printing_settings': '{"infill_pattern":"grid","top_layers":6,"wall_line_count":3,"bottom_layers":6,"layer_height":0.5,"infill_density":90}', 'annotations': '{"load":[],"anchor":[]}'}
```

When i type `print(type(data))` i get `<class 'dict'>`

Then i call a function and pass it this json as an argument:

```
outcome = myfunction(data)
```

I get this error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`
in this line:  `layer_height = params_dict["printing_settings"]["layer_height"]`

I tried this as well:

```
layer_height = int(params_dict["printing_settings"]["layer_height"])
layer_height = float(params_dict["printing_settings"]["layer_height"])
```

What's even stranger is that i get this error even when i try to print the details about `params_dict["printing_settings"]["layer_height"]`.

For example, when i use:

```
print(type(params_dict["printing_settings"]["layer_height"]))
```

or

```
print(params_dict["printing_settings"]["layer_height"])
```

These two lines give me the same error as well. At this point, i am stuck.

Comment: your dict seems to have strings inside instead of other dicts

Comment: That's not strange. You are trying to index a string with a string. That won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have the sub_dictionaries as string e.g
Try this

```
{"translate":{"z":-1.2,"y":-3,"x":-2},"scale":{"y":2,"z":2,"x":2},"rotate":{"x":90,"z":20,"y":80}}
```

instead of this

```
'{"translate":{"z":-1.2,"y":-3,"x":-2},"scale":{"y":2,"z":2,"x":2},"rotate":{"x":90,"z":20,"y":80}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your string to dict:

```
layer_height = json.loads(data["printing_settings"])["layer_height"]
```

or

```
import ast

for k, v in data.items():
    if isinstance(v, str) and "{" in v:
        data[k] = ast.literal_eval(v)

data
```